# Database structure of Facebook to store comments and post?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, facebook, social-networking

I'm going to create simple social networking site.
so... I want to know that how Facebook store comments for posts.

is Facebook store Posts and its comments in same database table row,
then how they store a long list of comments in a one table row field.
or is it have each database table for each post, so that can make the comments for that post in that table row.

What is the best database structure for a simple social network site like CMS.
but it could be handle a large amount of users.

Please help me in this matter.
Thanks.

Comment: "is facebook store Posts and its comments in same databse table row" it will never happen. they have deffrent tables for comments and post (i think)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Small example of what you could do:

Table **users**:

```
users
--------
id
name
```

Table **comments**:

```
comments
--------
id
comment_text
posted_by
posted_to
date_posted
```

When user with ID 342 posts a comment to user 783's profile, you can store the comment like so:

```
INSERT INTO comments(comment_text, posted_by, posted_to, date_posted) 
VALUES ('Hi!', 342, 783, '2013-10-16 11:17:00');
```

Then, when you're selecting comments to show on a user's profile, simply join the posted_by and posted_to columns up with the relevant ids in the users table.

Comment: Shouldn't you be storing the `post_id` in the `posted_to` column?

Comment: @Peter I did forget to add the date_posted column to my insert statement. posted_to should be the unique ID of the user profile that the comment is being published on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess they have a table with all posts and the post_id. Then they have another table with all comments. And in the comments_table they have a row with the post_id so they can assign it.

So,

every Post has a post_id with the status text, id of the user who wrote it etc.
and every comment has a comment_id and a post_id to assign it to the post.

That's what I'm guessing. I can't tell you for sure though.

Simple example
**UPDATE**

posts-table

```
post_id | user_id | status_text | datetime
```

comments-table

```
comments_id | user_id | post_id | comments_text | datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

i think for comment you try this table
it table for video song thaty it collect a column with track id name

```
              CREATE TABLE `tbl_video_comments` (                       
                  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,           
                  `user_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,                   
                  `track_id` int(11) NOT NULL,                            
                  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,                           
                  `comment` varchar(100) NOT NULL,                        
                  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)                              
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

All that you need is the relaeation and three table for now. Just keep the userid as primary key in the user table and make it foreign in every table you create. That will help you in getting every thing on basis of the userid.